# Break a string by first occurrence of a non-letter character?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have strings like these:

```
asdf.123
asdf_123
asdf123
as123df
```

How could I split by any non-letter character to get this:

```
asdf
asdf
asdf
as
```

Comment: you want to remove the text after any non character ? or just remove non letter character

Comment: @NitinJ Yes. So `as123df` should return `as`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method:

```
regexp = /^[a-z]+/i

'asdf.123'[regexp]
# => "asdf"

'as123df'[regexp]
# => "as"

'ASas123'[regexp]
# => "ASas"
```

Comment: this will not take care of character in Uppper case [A-Z]

Comment: Because of the `i` modifier, as described in the [literals documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Regular+Expressions).

Comment: I think this is better than my solution +1

Answer (score 5):

```
"your string".split(/[^A-Za-z]/).first
```

Will split by anything not in A-Z or a-z and then return the first result.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply just replace all non-alpha characters using `gsub(/\W+/, '')` with a regex expression...

Comment: But I don't want any letters after a non-alpha character is reached. So `as123df` should return `as`.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
  a = "string 1232"
  a[/[a-zA-Z]+/]
  # => "string"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you `"aaas._123ff".gsub!(/[^a-zA-Z].*/, '')`

```
 => "aaas"
```

Comment: Could use `sub` instead of `gsub`, and I would not personally suggest destructively mutating the original string.